# What are the difference between these two sentences?

Tags: grammar, meaning, participles

- *The bullied schoolboy appeared on television,* and
- *The bullying schoolboy appeared on television*.

What is the difference in meaning. Is it that the 1st sentence subject is the victim?

Comment: _Is the subject of the first sentence the victim?_ Yes.

Answer (score 1):

The subject in the two sentences is, indeed, different. The subject of the first sentence is the victim.

The use of the participle form of a verb as an adjective to modify nouns is described on [grammarly.com](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/participle/).